# Flask-Admin: How to change model using on_model_change?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-admin

I'm trying to set a field's value to be based on another field in the same form:

```
    def on_model_change(form, model, is_created):
        model.textcolumn.data = model.textcolumn2.data
```

Updating via the Flask-Admin interface raises no exceptions, but no changes were made to the value in model.textcolumn.

Inspecting the "model" object, I also noticed this is not the same as the SQLAlchemy model used to generate the ModelView.

How can I change model.textcolumn's value to model.textcolumn2's value? Is there a way to access the SQLAlchemy model object directly? This would be much better.

Comment: It turns out "model" is the SQLAlchemy model all along. I was missing the "self" argument in the function overload definition:

`def on_model_change(self, form, model, is_created):`

which caused all other arguments to be misnamed.

Answer (score 3):

I did it using the admin form for a specific model

```
class YourModelAdmin(MyModelView):
    form_overrides = dict(filename=FileField)

    def on_model_change(self, form, instance):
        pass

   admin.add_view(YourModelAdmin(YourModel, db.session))
```

Comment: What does `class` on line 5 represent in your example?

Comment: thanks @AlisonS it was a typo. where it was written "class" I meant "pass"